# How do some navigation bars on websites get the vertical lines in between different menu options?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below follows the [nav bar of a website](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/color-psychology-of-color-and-conversions) that I'm trying to emulate:

[image]

Here is my nav bar:

[image]

I would like to have the vertical lines to separate the menu options but upon inspecting the elements of that website, I can't seem to figure out how. Is it drawn in as part of the menu option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your right border as follows:

```
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
```

It looks like that is what the site there is doing.

Good luck!!

Comment: First element has left border as it is in image (use :first-child or :last-child)

Comment: `div:first-child { border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15); }`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div>HOME</div>
    <div>SOMETHING</div>
    <div>SOMETHING ELSE</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#nav div {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}

#nav div:last-child {
    border-right: none
}
```

Here's a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/TE5zT/

Or if you want borders on both sides:

[image]

```
#nav div {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #000
}

#nav div:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TE5zT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use below color value for border-right CSS property.

```
#nav div {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #4379ab
}

#nav div:last-child {
    border-right: none
}
```